# delete a (specialised) signature in an interface

Tags: inheritance, typescript

Is it possible to delete (a specialisation of) an inherited signature in an interface in TypeScript?

```
interface ComplexNumber {
  divideBy(b: number): ComplexNumber;
}

interface RealNumber extends ComplexNumber {
  delete divideBy(0);
  rationalize(): [number, number];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Despite it could seem like a way to go - it is **NOT**, see more here: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Hm, true :) Even though it seemed it would be useful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible.

But, probably, you will be interested in **optional parameters/methods**. As I understood, you want to use the interface **RealNumber** for a class which doesn't have an implementation of the method **dividedBy**. If it's true, the next thing might be useful for you:

```
interface ComplexNumber {
  divideBy?(b: number): ComplexNumber;
}

interface RealNumber extends ComplexNumber {
  rationalize(): [number, number];
  ...
}
```

Please, pay attention to the **?** sign after the name of the method **divideBy** (it means, that this method is optional and classes might have this method, but also they might don't have it, because it's an optional method).

Comment: `delete divideBy()` is not valid syntax, I just invented it as a demonstration of what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @PeterVarga Oh, sorry, forgot to remove this line. The main thing in my code is the line with: `divideBy?(b: number): ComplexNumber;`